# Get sum of values in between two dates with same month references

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to sum all entries between two monthly incomes with the same reference. Example:

```
Month 1
Payment Date  Ref          Amount
03/11/2018  donations1     £  10
05/11/2018  donations2     £  90
07/11/2018  donations3     £ 100
01/11/2018  Gift Aid       £ 200  (Needs to be the sum of donations)

11/11/2018  donation4      £ 30
12/11/2018  donations5     £ 20
10/11/2018  Gift Aid       £ 50   (Needs to be the sum of donations)
```

In between **all donations** the sum of the donations (1,2,3) needs to be equal to **all donations** and its subsequent entries throughout the year, in order to display a full year report.
How do I perform this using **LINQ in C#**?
I am using an MVC approach.

Code taken from Gufus and adjusted to my code (great help!), but still not what I am looking for:

```
var listGaDonations = db.Upload
                .Where(x => x.IsGiftAid == true)
                .ToList();

            var list = from e in listGaDonations
                where e.FirstName != "Gift Aid"
                       group e.Amount by e.Ref
                into p
                select new
                {
                    Ref = p.Key,
                    Amount = p.Sum()
                };
            var listJoined = from p in list
                join e in listGaDonations on p.Ref equals e.Ref
                group e.PaymentDate by p
                into a
                select new
                {
                    a.Key.Ref,
                    a.Key.Amount,
                    PaymentDate = a.Max()
                };
            foreach (var p in listJoined)
            {
                Upload e = new Upload(p.Ref, "Gift Aid", p.PaymentDate, p.Amount);
                listGaDonations.Add(e);
            }

            var sortentries = from e in listGaDonations
                orderby e.Ref, e.PaymentDate
                select e;

            var test = sortentries.Where(x => x.PaymentDate != DateTime.MinValue).ToList();

            return View(test);
```

The results I've got:

```
 Ref:      Donation    Payment Date    Amount
CIZ3S42J    don1        19/08/2018     £100.00
EG066AUM    don2        01/08/2018     £123.00
EUGOP7T9    don3        04/09/2018     £55.00
GRMEV47F    Gift Aid    02/09/2018     £xxx   (Which is not the sum of 
                                                donations)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: None of your data is labeled "reference" - what is the "same reference"? Why do you have a label "Month 1" when the dates are in different months? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please show the code you're using to store the data. Also, can you clarify what you are asking? I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to sum the "All donations" values? Perhaps some sample output data would help.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't have a code as I just want to display a sum of values between the dates with reference "all donations" which happens 4 times a month. How can I perform this action in LINQ

Comment: Why is -according to your requirement- donation3 not summed in the first gift aid of 01/11/2018, while donation4 isn't? Is it because it is later in your input sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to interpret your indication, so I think you have to define the class of entries more or less in this way

```
public class Entry
    {
        private int _reference; 
        private string _donation;
        private DateTime _date;
        private double _amount;

        public Entry(int aReference, string aDonation, DateTime aDate, double aAmount)
            {
                _reference = aReference;
                _donation = aDonation;
                _date = aDate;
                _amount = aAmount;
            }

        public double Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set { _amount = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; }
        }

        public string Donation
        {
            get { return _donation; }
            set { _donation = value; }
        }

        public int Reference 
        {
            get { return _reference; }
            set { _reference = value; }
        }
}
```

I'm sure there could be smarter way to write the program, but the following seems to work

```
List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

            entries.Add(new Entry(1, "donation 1", new DateTime(2018, 11, 3), 10));
            entries.Add(new Entry(1, "donation 2", new DateTime(2018, 11, 5), 90));
            entries.Add(new Entry(1, "donation 3", new DateTime(2018, 11, 7), 100));
            entries.Add(new Entry(2, "donation 4", new DateTime(2018, 11, 11), 30));
            entries.Add(new Entry(2, "donation 5", new DateTime(2018, 11, 12), 20));

            var list = from e in entries
                       where e.Donation != "partial total"
                       group e.Amount by e.Reference into p
                       select new
                       {
                           Reference = p.Key,
                           Amount = p.Sum()
                       };

            var listjoined = from p in list
                             join e in entries on p.Reference equals e.Reference
                             group e.Date by p into a
                             select new
                             {
                                 Reference = a.Key.Reference,
                                 Amount = a.Key.Amount,
                                 Date = a.Max()
                             };


            foreach(var p in listjoined)
            {
                Entry e = new Entry(p.Reference, "partial total", p.Date, p.Amount);
                entries.Add(e);
            }
            var sortedentries = from e in entries
                                orderby e.Reference, e.Date
                                select e;

            foreach(var e in sortedentries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Reference}; {e.Donation} occurred on {e.Date}; the amount is of {e.Amount} USD");
            }
```

if you want total by months you just have to put a where clause where you hold only partial total (or you throw away them and hold single donations: you just have to be sure to avoid double-counting) and group amounts by month date (this is something similar to what I did in list).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this code tomorrow and I'll let.ypu know, but thanks anyway.

Comment: ah, when I calculated the partial total i put the max date between the linked entries: in your example you did something different (for example donations of 11 and 12 november have "all donations" with date the 10th), if you need it tell what's the idea

Comment: Hi Gufus, thanks for your help.  I have updated my question using your code.  I can't still get the results expected.  Can you help please!  Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work because I've assumed that the field Reference has to be equal for all the entries you have to sum to calculate the "Gift Aid" entry. In your update I read Reference values like CIZ3S42J, EG066AUM ecc...if you look how I build the class Entry the first field of the constructor is 1 for the first entries and 2 for the remaining two. When I group by I use that field as a key, so in the "Gift Aid" I have the sums expected.

Comment: So you have to build another field and use it for grouping. Otherwise you can correct the values of Reference as I did (so you have to make very small changes to the code) and build a new field with values like CIZ3S42J, EG066AUM ecc...

Comment: another thing; looking at your code a doubt came to me: when you read data at the beginning the entry GRMEV47F    Gift Aid    02/09/2018     £xxx  is already present?

Comment: ok! you're very close to the win!! If you need some help don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Guff, what about if I have refs like my output?

Comment: how do you identify the entries that you want to sum to give a value to the "Gift Aid" entry? this is the key of the issue. In the first example you've chosen to sum the first three entries together in an entry and the last two in another one. How do you choose this distinction?

Comment: This is the situation:  donors donate every week (using random ref), and the sum of this entries need to be equal to an entry donations ("Gift Aid") which occurs on weekends. The key donations ("Gift Aid") is the sum of all other donations.  Hope you can understand.

Comment: so you need an index for each week. group by this instead of reference and you'll solve the issue

Comment: Hi, I know I've been asking too much, but can you update the code in order to achieve what you said ? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184562/discussion-between-gufus-and-prezequias).

Answer (score 0):

New version; I'm under the assumption that at the beginning you don't have "Gift Aid" records without amount.

I modified the class of Entry just changing the Reference which is a string instead of an int

```
public class Entry
    {
        private string _reference; 
        private string _donation;
        private DateTime _date;
        private double _amount;

        public Entry(string aReference, string aDonation, DateTime aDate, double aAmount)
            {
                _reference = aReference;
                _donation = aDonation;
                _date = aDate;
                _amount = aAmount;
            }

        public double Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set { _amount = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; }
        }

        public string Donation
        {
            get { return _donation; }
            set { _donation = value; }
        }

        public string Reference 
        {
            get { return _reference; }
            set { _reference = value; }
        }

        }
```

I've added a class derived from Entry which is Entry2:

```
public class Entry2:Entry
    {
        private DateTime _date2;

        public Entry2(string aReference, string aDonation, DateTime aDate, double aAmount, DateTime aDate2)
        :base(aReference, aDonation, aDate, aAmount)
        {
            _date2 = aDate2;
        }

        public DateTime Date2
        {
            get { return _date2; }
            set { _date2 = value; }
        }
    }
```

Entry2 has a DateTime field more than Entry; your data are in the form of Entry, I transform them into Entry2 objects where the added argument is valorized with the following Sunday respect to the DateTime in the object Entry. To assign this value I used the following function

```
public static DateTime NextSunday(DateTime aDate)
        {

            if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Monday") { return aDate.AddDays(6); }
            else if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Tuesday") { return aDate.AddDays(5); }
            else if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Wednesday") { return aDate.AddDays(4); }
            else if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Thursday") { return aDate.AddDays(3); }
            else if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Friday") { return aDate.AddDays(2); }
            else if (aDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday") { return aDate.AddDays(1); }
            else { return aDate; }
        }
```

Finally...the program! You can see that I group by the new DateTime field. There are only two queries (instead of two) because now I don't need to calculate a date to associate to the "Gift Aid" entry linked to the respective donations, because now I've built it at the beginning with the NextSunday method

```
List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

            entries.Add(new Entry("d1", "donation 1", new DateTime(2018, 11, 3), 10));
            entries.Add(new Entry("d2", "donation 2", new DateTime(2018, 11, 5), 90));
            entries.Add(new Entry("d3", "donation 3", new DateTime(2018, 11, 7), 100));
            entries.Add(new Entry("d4", "donation 4", new DateTime(2018, 11, 11), 30));
            entries.Add(new Entry("d5", "donation 5", new DateTime(2018, 11, 12), 20));

            List<Entry2> entries2 = new List<Entry2>();
            foreach(var e in entries) 
            {
                entries2.Add(new Entry2(e.Reference, e.Donation, e.Date, e.Amount, NextSunday(e.Date)));
            }

            var list = from e in entries2
                       where e.Donation != "Gift Aid"
                       group e.Amount by e.Date2 into p
                       select new
                       {
                           Date2 = p.Key,
                           Amount = p.Sum()
                       };
foreach(var p in list)
            {
                Entry e = new Entry("Some code", "Gift Aid", p.Date2, p.Amount);
                entries.Add(e);
            }
            var sortedentries = from e in entries
                                orderby e.Date
                                select e;

            foreach(var e in sortedentries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Reference}; {e.Donation} occurred on {e.Date}; the amount is of {e.Amount} USD");
            }
```

I repeat, I'm under an assumption that could be very relevant: I've asked you informations about that in the comment but you never asked me. One more problem could the type of Amount: in your data is it number? If it is a string you could have problems doing sums...

The result of the program is different from your example because 3, 5 and 7 november are not in the same week, that's why 3 remains alone while 3, 5's amounts are summed (with also the amount of 11/11 because it's in the same week of 3 and 5).

Hope it helps!